# Installing HoboFields Pre-Release for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, hobo

I'm trying to install the latest pre-release version of [HoboFields](http://hobocentral.net/hobofields/), which supports Rails 3 (RubyGems doesn't have the latest code). I've followed the steps on the [relevant Hobo blog post](http://hobocentral.net/blog/2010/08/24/hobofields-and-rails-3/), but when I execute `rake install`, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'install'
```

Can anyone help me with this? How can I successfully install the latest pre-release version of HoboFields so that it will work with Rails 3?

**Note:** I'm trying to use HoboFields, not Hobo. The latter I've installed successfully, but I'd like to use just HoboFields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the latest pre-release version of HoboFields by using the `--pre` option:

```
sudo gem install hobo_fields --pre
```

A more detailed discussion showing how this problem was solved can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/hobousers/browse_frm/thread/ea15132db031409c).